# DELAY issues: how to apply styles immediately or not show loaded webpage until styles are applied?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiwebview

**Technologies Used:** XCode 6, iOS8, Swift

I'm loading a webpage in a uiwebview and I'm also appending a new stylesheet to the body of that webpage and overwriting some of its styles. But, there is a delay (maybe 1 second or 2) between when the webpage loads and the styles are applied so you can see the webpage before its restyled. I'm using javascript to append the new styles to the body of the webpage. How can I fix this so that the webpage will only show with the styles are already applied? Here is my code:

import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {

```
@IBOutlet var website: UIWebView!

var url = "http://www.fake-website-url.net"

func loadUrl() {
    let requestURL = NSURL(string: url)
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: requestURL!)
    website.loadRequest(request)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    website.delegate = self
    loadUrl()
}

func webViewDidFinishLoad(website: UIWebView) {
    var loadStyles = "var script = document.createElement('link');script.type = 'text/css';script.rel = 'stylesheet';script.href = 'http://fake-url.styles.css';document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(script);"
    website.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString(loadStyles)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

Note, I'm using Swift.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is create a property to store the downloaded page. Then override the property setter to add your custom style sheet after the page is saved to that property. Then finally load it into your Web View.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Hi Erion - thanks for your thoughts - could you give me a code example of implementing something like that?

Comment: I have never used Swift before, only objective c sorry. That's why I did not include any code. Here is a link I found that may help you. http://blog.johnregner.com/post/103092814578/swift-properties-custom-setters-and-getters